# Waiting for css property value in testcafe

Tags: css, node.js, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I want to wait for an element to have a specific value in CSS property.

To be more specific I'm making some functional tests using Testcafe and they should wait until the opacity is increased from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've came up with this solution and it seems to work as I've expected.

```js
async waitForOpacity(selector, options) {
        const settings = Object.assign(
            {
                timeout: 30000,
                checkInterval: 300,
            },
            options
        );
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let passedTime = 0;
            const intervalVisible = setInterval(async () => {
                const visible = await selector.visible;
                const opacity = await selector.getStyleProperty('opacity');
                passedTime = passedTime + settings.checkInterval;
                if (visible && opacity > 0) {
                    clearInterval(intervalVisible);
                    return resolve();
                }
                if (passedTime >= settings.timeout) {
                    clearInterval(intervalVisible);
                    return reject(new Error('Element did not become visible'));
                }
            }, settings.checkInterval);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use standard TestCafe [Assertion](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/) mechanism? You can write something like this

```js
const opacity = await selector.getStyleProperty('opacity');
await t.expect(opacity).eql(1, {timeout: 5000})
```

Timeout option usually set in runner function, but can be specified for each assertion separately. It will pass as soon, as condition will be truthfully or will fail after 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for answer but have you actually tried that? :)
As far as I can tell `await selector.getStyleProperty('opacity')` will evaluate and assign the current value and it won't be evaluated again with `expect`

Comment: It didn't work? I don't have page with animation or changing css property right now, but as far as i understand official documentation, if assertion was failed within timeout range, testcafe will retrive actual value again, and will do it, until timeout expires. Quote from doc:

if an assertion did not pass, the test does not fail immediately. The assertion retries to pass multiple times, and each time it requests the actual property value. The test fails if the assertion could not complete successfully within a timeout

Comment: It did not work when I've tried it. I don't think this contradicts the docs since you're comparing constant value to 1. It may even try for an hour still this constant would not change.
`const opacity = await selector.getStyleProperty('opacity');`
`// At this point opacity is already equal to a number e.g. 0`
`// It's not a selector that can be evaluated by eql again to change the value`
`await t.expect(opacity).eql(1, {timeout: 5000});`

Comment: This should work if you allow testcafe to await the element and property as outlined in the [docs](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/).  `await t.expect(selector.getStyleProperty('opacity')).eql(1, {timeout: 5000})` or `const opacity = selector.getStyleProperty('opacity');` and `await t.expect(opacity).eql(1, {timeout: 5000})`

Answer (score 1):

Follows an workout solution, where you have some comments that explains the code.

For more info about how the MutationObserver works, you can check in [here](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-tracking-changes-in-the-dom-using-mutationobserver-86adc7446401).

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    //When style property change, this function will be called
    mutations.forEach((mutationRecord) => {
        //YOU SHOULD IMPLEMENT YOUR <<BUSINESS CODE>> IN HERE
        //Then, i check the value of the opacity and see if is equals to 0
        if($(myTest).css('opacity') == 1)
          console.log("opacity changed");
    });    
});

//Element that will be the target of the observable
var target = document.getElementById('myTest');
observer.observe(target, { 
                           attributes : true, 
                           attributeFilter : ['style'] 
                         }
                );

/*Simulates the opacity change on an element*/
setTimeout(() => $(myTest).css('opacity',1), 2000)
```

```css
#myTest{
   opacity:0;
   width:30px;
   height:30px;
   background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myTest"></div>
```